# udev rule to run shell script when any hard drive is hotswapped

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, udev

I want to run a custom `sh`-script each time a hard drive is hotswapped into my computer, regardless of the drive's make, model, or other specifications.

My udev rule under `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-TEST-RULE.rules` reads:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd*", RUN+="/usr/loca/bin/DRIVE_INSERT_MESSAGE.sh"
```

I reloaded `udev` rules a few times, and restarted my device after most changes. What's going wrong ?

Comment: Additionally, I would not like to count drive sda because that drive will always be in the system, however sd[b-z] are fair game.

Comment: Check the logs and, if something comes up there, please add it to your question. Try to keep DRIVE_INSERT_MESSAGE.sh as simple as possible, something like just a `touch` command, so that you know if it runs or not.

Comment: Please show us the content of `/usr/loca/bin/DRIVE_INSERT_MESSAGE.sh` by editing your OP and adding it there.

Answer (score 0):

### Nature of the problem

The problem you are running into is that `udevd` does not run in the root linux kernel namespaces by default in Ubuntu.

```
# ps -axe -o user,pid,ipcns,mntns,netns,pidns,userns,utsns,comm | awk '$3!="-"' | grep -E "udevd|$$|MNTNS"
USER         PID      IPCNS      MNTNS      NETNS      PIDNS     USERNS      UTSNS COMMAND
root         477 4026531839 4026532239 4026531840 4026531836 4026531837 4026532259 systemd-udevd
root     1663933 4026531839 4026531841 4026531840 4026531836 4026531837 4026531838 bash
```

Any mounts that `udevd` makes are not visible to the rest of the processes running on the machine. Your `DRIVE_INSERT_MESSAGE.sh` script is running in namespaces that cannot communicate with a lot of the rest of the system.

To further debug your problem, run `sudo nsenter --all -t $(pgrep systemd-udevd) /bin/bash` which will put you into a shell that is in all of the same kernel namespaces as `udevd`. You can then poke around and tune your `DRIVE_INSERT_MESSAGE.sh` script.

### See also

- `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d` for reference udev rules
- `udevadm` for interacting with udev, EG triggering udev events while troubleshooting
- `sudo systemctl edit systemd-udevd` to tweak the udevd systemctl unit
- `udevadm test-builtin --help` to list builtin udev modules

### TL;DR

It is very likely that your script is running, but it is running in restricted kernel namespaces.